# Why do I get " UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning" and what does it mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronization

I am trying to read and write to a CSV file, and I am quite new to javascript. My code seems to make sense to me but I am not sure why it isn't running.

```
app.post('/name=:name/available=:available/type=:type/subtype=:subtype/ip=:ip', (req, res) => {
  csvtojson().fromFile(csvFilePath).then((objects) => {
    objectsArray = objects;
    const newItem = {
      id: objectsArray.length + 1, 
      name: req.params.name,
      available: req.params.available
    };

    csvWriter.writeRecords(objectsArray).then( () => {
      console.log("Csv File Created!");
      console.log(objectsArray);
      res.json(objectsArray);
    });
   });
});
```

From what I can see, I should first read the CSV file, then save the contents in an array, then create an object, then write the object into the CSV file. But I get the errors: "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked", and  "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)"

Comment: In the inner function you use a promise(`.then()`). those should always have a final `.catch()` callback to handle any errors within the callbacks. NodeJS since a while issues a warning, if such a callback is missing (but would have been triggered).

Comment: Are you asking why you get the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`?  Or are you asking why your code gets an `EBUSY` error (that you have no error handler for)?  The warning is telling you that you got an error and you had no code to handle that error.  That's a bug.  If have no idea why you got the error in the first place, but obviously there's something wrong with the code, configuration or some resource you're trying to use.

Comment: All promises (that could ever reject with an error) MUST have an error handler (either a `.catch()` or a `try/catch` if using `await` or the 2nd argument to `.then()`).  You have two asynchronous operations that return a promise.  You have no error handling on either one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` comes becomes one of your two asynchronous operations is encountering an `EBUSY` error and you have no error handler for that error.  The node.js runtime sees that a promise was rejected, but there was no error handler for that and identifies that as a likely inappropriate coding situation (a bug) so it emits the warning.

In Javascript, EVERY promise operation that can ever reject must have an error handler.  An error handler for promise rejections can be done with a `.catch()`, a `try/catch` if the promise is `await`ed or with the 2nd argument to `.then()`.

You can add proper error handlers to your code and that will tell you a bit more about where the error is occurring and will get rid of the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.

```
app.post('/name=:name/available=:available/type=:type/subtype=:subtype/ip=:ip', (req, res) => {
  csvtojson().fromFile(csvFilePath).then((objects) => {
    const newItem = {
      id: objects.length + 1, 
      name: req.params.name,
      available: req.params.available
    };

    return csvWriter.writeRecords(objects).then( () => {
      console.log("Csv File Created!");
      console.log(objects);
      res.json(objects);
    });
   }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.sendStatus(500);
   });
});
```

If, for debugging purposes, you wanted to log the 2nd promise rejection separately, you could do this:

```
app.post('/name=:name/available=:available/type=:type/subtype=:subtype/ip=:ip', (req, res) => {
  csvtojson().fromFile(csvFilePath).then((objects) => {
    const newItem = {
      id: objects.length + 1, 
      name: req.params.name,
      available: req.params.available
    };

    return csvWriter.writeRecords(objects).then( () => {
      console.log("Csv File Created!");
      console.log(objects);
      res.json(objects);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log("csvWriter error", err);
      throw err;
    });
   }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.sendStatus(500);
   });
});
```

In this case, I've returned the 2nd promise which will chain it to the 1st promise so we can then add a single `.catch()` handler to the 1st promise and it will catch errors from either promise.  Then, the error handler sends a 500 status to complete the request handler.

I would guess that the EBUSY error has something to do with either reading from the file represented at `csvFilePath`or with the file that `csvWriter` is trying to write to.  It sounds like it could be a file exclusivity issue where it's opened for exclusive access while doesn't allow other readers/writers to have access to it.

We can't really help with that specific error without seeing more of the context of your code and understanding while files might have multiple readers/writers that creates some sort of contention.

---

FYI, it also looks like you should get rid of the `objectsArray` variable and just use `objects` instead.  `objectsArray` is not declared locally within this function.  If it is not declared at all, then it's an implicit global (which is bad).  If it is declared at a higher scope, then it's a variable that is potentially shared between users each making the same request (very bad bug).